# C# loop optimization

Tags: c#, performance, loops

i have this loop and it loops for large count like 30 000 times at least
i am looking for some way to improve it's performance
   DbRecordDictionary is derived from DictionaryBase class
here is the loop:

```
ArrayList noEnter = new ArrayList();
DbRecordDictionary oldArray = new DbRecordDictionary();
DbRecordDictionary userArray = new DbRecordDictionary();
DbRecordDictionary result = null;
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    if (noEnter.Contains(key))
    { //may need cast!
        if (count < 1)
            result.Add(key, userArray[key]);
        else if (oldArray.Count == 0)
            break;
        else if (oldArray.Contains(key))
            result.Add(key, userArray[key]);
    }                
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting. Don't use `. Just indent each line by at least four spaces.

Comment: Don't use `<code>` tags. They don't work. Select your code and press the 010101 button instead

Comment: you might consider including noEnter, userArray, oldArray declarations..

Comment: @Armen: can you believe I dumbly started scanning my keyboard for this mythical 010101 button?

Comment: noEnter is array list and the rest are derived from Dictionarybase class

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a Dictionary/Hashset for `oldArray`, but else there is not much you can do. Also `noEnter` if that is an array.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the variable `count` or the `oldArray` never changes during the loop, so you can place those condition outside the loop, and make two different loops.

```
if (count < 1) {
  foreach (string key in keys) {
    if (noEnter.Contains(key)) {
      result.Add(key, userArray[key]);
    }
  }
} else if (oldArray.Count == 0) {
  // no data
} else {
  foreach (string key in keys) {
    if (noEnter.Contains(key)) {
      if (oldArray.Contains(key)) {
        result.Add(key, userArray[key]);
      }
    }                
  }
}
```

The collections `noEnter` and `oldArray` should be dictionaries, otherwise you will be spending a lot of execution time in the `Contains` calls.

Answer (score 1):

If noEnter has more then about 10 items in it, then use a Dictionary rathern then a List/Array for it.   As a Dictionary can look up a item without having to look at all the items, when an List/Array has to loop over all items.

Otherwise consider shorting "keys" and "oldArray" and then  proforming a "merge" on them.  Look at the code for a "merge sort" to see how to do the merge.  (This would need carefull profiling)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(from k in keys
     where noEnter.Contains(k) &&
           oldArray.Count > 0 &&
           count < 1 &&
           oldArray.Contains(k)
     select k)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(k => result.Add(k, userArray[k]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Small small optimization could be using generics
ArrayList noEnter = new ArrayList(); would be List noEnter = new List();
and DbRecordDictionary would inherit Dictonary instead of DictionaryBase.

im not 100% sure that you would gain performance but you will use a more modern c# style.